# Product of a, b, and c

Tags: number-theory

Given three positive integers, $a$, $b$, and $c$, which are strictly greater than 1. If $abc$ divides $(ab - 1)(bc - 1) (ca - 1)$, what is the value of $abc$ ?

I am total blank. Help anyone ?

Comment: Have you tried expanding that product? Can you divide it by $abc$?

Comment: i have. as long as i know, it can't divide by abc

Comment: What expression do you get though? You should end up with some integers plus $1/a + 1/b + 1/c - 1/abc$. What conditions do $a$,$b$, and $c$ have to satisfy for that to be an integer?

Answer (score 1):

$abc|(ab-1)(bc-1)(ca-1)$

$abc|abbcca-abbc-abca+ab-bcca+bc+ca-1$

$abc|abc(abc-a-b-c)+ab+bc+ca-1$

$abc|ab+bc+ca-1$

So, $\frac{ab+bc+ca-1}{abc}=\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c-\frac1{abc}$ should be integer.

Since $a,b,c\gt 1$, the only value that the above could take is 1. So,

$\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c-\frac1{abc}=1$

$abc+1-ab-bc-ca=0$

Let's call this one, $f(a,b,c)$.

$f(a,b,c+1)-f(a,b,c)=ab-a-b\ge0$, since $a,b\ge2$

That means that if you try to increase any number of a,b,c then f(a,b,c) will increase.

Since $f(2,2,2)=-3, f(2,2,3)=-1, f(2,2,4)=1, f(2,3,3)=-2, f(3,3,3)=1$, none of these equals zero. And any other combination of a,b,c will we greater than zero.

so there are no integer values $a,b,c\ge2$